# The signer produced an invalid signature

Tags: baking, endorser, remote-signer, signature, missed-endorsement

I missed one of the endorsements due to an invalid signature. Why or how a remote-signer could produce an invalid signature? I am using a remote-signer with an HSM. Remote signer and HSM logs look good (no errors), and it has been working fine on the testnet (delphinet).

```
008-PtEdo2Zk.baking.endorsement: Error while injecting endorsement for delegate tz2...... : 
008-PtEdo2Zk.baking.endorsement:  Error:
008-PtEdo2Zk.baking.endorsement:   The signer for http://localhost:6732/tz2...... produced an invalid signature
```

Comment: Maybe related to it being a tz2 address? Do you have more detailed logs or information? This might be an issue more appropriate for https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/

Comment: @arvidj No, I don't have any more logs as it seems to be a tezos-client issue coming from here [https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/lib_client_base/client_keys.ml#L321](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/lib_client_base/client_keys.ml#L321). I have even verified the signature using the taquito api and it is a valid signature.